# How to compare &self in struct's method with another struct

Tags: rust

I'm not sure why but my method won't work, is there a way to compare self with its parent struct? I added the data structures for context.

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Copy, Clone, Debug)]
enum Suits {
    Hearts,
    Spades,
    Clubs,
    Diamonds,
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Copy, Clone, Debug)]
struct Card {
    card_num: u8,
    card_suit: Suits,
}



    fn match_card(&self, deck: &[Option<Card>]) -> bool {
        for i in deck.iter() {
            match i.unwrap() {
                self => {
                    println!("\nFound card in deck!\nCard found is {:#?}\n", i.unwrap());
                    return true;
                }
                _ => continue,
            }
        }
        false
    }
```

I get:

```
`self` value is a keyword and may not be bound to variables or shadowed
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `match` statement matches the provided value against *patterns*. Matching a value against a pattern is different from testing for equality. If the latter is what you want to do, use an `if` statement instead. You can read up on patterns in the [subsection on pattern syntax in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html).

A pattern consisting of just an identifier, say `x`, matches whatever value is provided, and this value is *assigned* to `x`. This means the pattern `self` does not compare the value with the value of `self`, but instead tries to assign the value of the match expression to `self`, which is not allowed, as the error message explains.

Your function should instead be written like this:

```
fn match_card(&self, deck: &[Option<Card>]) -> bool {
    deck.iter().flatten().any(|card| card == self)
}
```

This assumes that `PartialEq` is implemented for the `Card` type, which can usually be done using `#[derive(PartialEq)]`.

The `flatten()` method in the code above treats each `Option<Card>` as a nested iterator. Iterating an `Option` yields no elements if the option is `None`, or otherwise the single value wrapped in the option. This means that `deck.iter().flatten()` is an iterator yielding an `&Card` for all `Some(_)` items in the slice, while all `None` items are simply skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Card` implements `PartialEq`, you may use a [match guard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/guard.html):

```
fn match_card(&self, deck: &[Option<Card>]) -> bool {
    for i in deck.iter() {
        match i {
            Some(c) if c == self => {
                println!("\nFound card in deck!\nCard found is {:#?}\n", c);
                return true;
            }
            _ => continue,
        }
    }
    false
}
```

[playground demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b989cf3abe32589c2ce81de3aadbe9b5)

I can't tell what the real code is, but if you have no reason to use a `match`, a simple `if` test would be more appropriate here.